# Как поместить выпадающий список под основное меню?

Tags: html, css

Ссылка на пен с проблемой: http://codepen.io/kostanakis/pen/MepJYq

В текущем коде выпадающее меню отображается поверх основной панели меню.
В голову приходит использовать z-index, но данный параметр не работает с position: absolute. Если для него выставить `position:relative;`, то становится еще хуже. Как быть?

UPD:Нюанс еще в том, что если сместить блок выпадающего меню ниже, то при перемещении курсора на этот блок пропадает :hover, меню скрывается.

Comment: уберите поднятие ссылки, курсор дергается http://i.imgur.com/ewfJHDK.gif

Comment: Такое количество кода лень читать. [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте поменять отступ сверху для вложенного  и поставить к примеру 15px в CSS строке 55-56.

```
.nav ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 -30%;
    padding: 5px 0 0 1em;
}
```

А чтобы весь список выглядел еще более аккуратно, можно поправить margin и paddding для `<ul>` и `<li>`.

И старайтесь использовать для задания либо "px", либо "em", а то у вас используются и те и другие прямо в одной строке.